# Couples in the movie theater

Tags: combinatorics

In a movie theater rows have 20 seats.

If each couple must always remain united,

how many different ways 6 couples can occupy a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider each valid arrangement of couples. For each empty seat, write a 1, and for each couple, write a 0.

The result is a string with six $0$'s and eight $1$'s.

There are $\binom{14}{6}$ such strings.

Now multiply by 6! to determine the order of the 6 couples, and $2^6$ to determine the order within each couple.

The answer is $\binom{14}{6} \times 6! \times 2^6$.

Comment: Yes! Perfect! Thanks a lot.